# Creating two and one condition in a program

Tags: python, input, output, conditional-statements

I have a code that allows a user to choose between 3 options
0- Beginner
1- Intermediate
2: Advanced

The code I have is:

```
if inp == 0:
    out = "Beginner"

elif inp == 1:
    out = "Intermediate"

elif inp == 2:
    out = "Advanced"

else:
    print("Invalid")
```

However, I'm wanting it so if a number greater than 3 was entered, it won't proceed to the second part.

The second part of the code I have is:

```
x=float(input("Choose a number between [0,90]"))
if x > 0 and x < 90:
    print("Is Latitude in the North or South Hemisphere?")
else:
    print ("Invalid")
```

Can someone provide some insight into how the condition is supposed to be?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with your code if you test for the existence of `out` before the second section.
You just need to initialise `out` before the if

```
out = ""
if inp == 0:
    out = "Beginner"
elif inp == 1:
    out = "Intermediate"
elif inp == 2:
    out = "Advanced"
else:
    print("Invalid")
```

Now, because `out` has become a global variable, you can test for whether or not `out` has been set. If `out` is not set, this next section is skipped.

```
if out:
    x=float(input("Choose a number between [0,90]"))
    if x > 0 and x < 90:
    print("Is Latitude in the North or South Hemisphere?")
    else:
        print ("Invalid")
```

Realistically though, there's a ton of different ways you can do this. Personally, I'd probably use a function and then a `return` statement out of it to stop execution, but you can also break out and stop things that way or use some form of loop to wait for the variable you want.

The great thing and the frustrating thing about programming is there's normally more than one way to get it right.